# Calling server side event from html button control in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an ASP.NET MVC project with a HTML button,

```
<input runat="server" class="btn" value="Sign in" name="" 
       type="submit" onserverclick="btn_OnClick"/>
```

And I put a script tag at the top of the cshtml file

```
<script language="C#" runat="server">
protected void btn_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    console.log("Button has been clicked.")
}
</script>
```

The text between the script tags appears as white so I don't think it recognizes what I'm trying to do, and it doesn't log in the console as it should do. Do I have to put the code somewhere else?

Comment: It seems to me, you are trying to combine webform control with MVC, which are not compatible.

Comment: So I really **have** to use an asp button? Or what other options do I have?

Comment: Page Methods. But that's ASP.NET AJAX, with scriptmanager.

Comment: I mean, there must be one way to do it right?